# azure project msbuild is not copying app.config

Tags: azure, msbuild, app-config

When deploying an Azure worker role project from Visual studio, everything works fine.

When we build the package using command line msbuild, the apps.config is not copied to project.dll.config.
How can we achieve that?

**Note:** 
the msbuild command builds a cspkg file (which is a zip).
When we open the zip file, project.dll.config is not here.

Config: Visual studio 2013

azure sdk 2.3

**Note 2:**
When you create an azure solution in visual studio, it creates 2 project:

- One Azure project.
- One worker role project.

This is the Azure project that is built, and the app.config belongs to the worker role project.
Deploying through Visual studio makes the magic automatically, msbuild.exe does not ( or we don't know how to do it).

Answer (score 0):

Is the App.config correctly specified in your .csproj file? You should have something similar to:

```
<Content Include="app.config">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Content>
```

Somewhere in your .csproj file.

Comment: the projects are automatically created by visual studio when you create an azure worker role project and compiles and deploy fine from within visual studio. It's when it's built and deployed from command line that app.config is not deployed. Not sure to understand if you suggestion fixes the problem

Comment: at theadriangreen: the app.config does not belong to the project compiled. We compile the azure project and this is the app.config of the worker role that is missing.

Comment: When enabling compilation logs in visual studio, here is what I'm getting. This is missing when using msbuild.exe:

Comment: 11>Target "CopyWorkerRoleFiles" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.3\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" from project "C:\svn\MAIL\MailWorker-Azure\CIW.Mails.Worker.Azure.ccproj" (target "CopyRoleFiles" depends on it):
11> WorkerFiles=C:\svn\MAIL\MailWorker\App.config -> CIW.Mails.dll.config